# Javascript function Wicket test

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, testing, wicket

I have an ajaxEditableLabelWithIcon which is a ajaxEditableLabel with a modified HTML that contain an icon. When the user click this icon, the editor field become editable and when he click again, the content is saved. We did that using JQuery :

```
function editOrSubmit(element){

panel = element.parentElement;
    label = panel.children[0];
    if(panel.find){
        e = $.Event('keypress');
        e.which = 13; // Enter key
        label.trigger(e); //submit the FormTester
    }
    else{
        label.click(); //Wich make the label editable
    }
}
```

Now, I want to test it using JUnit. Since I can't directly click on the icon, I tried to create a javascript shortcut to the function, and then create a Robot to trigger the KeyPressed events :

```
// defining flags
var isCtrl = false;
var isShift = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    // action on key up
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 17) {
            isCtrl = false;
        }
        if(e.which == 16) {
            isShift = false;
        }
    });
    // action on key down
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 17) {
            isCtrl = true; 
        }
        if(e.which == 16) {
            isShift = true; 
        }
        // En cas d'appui sur ctrl+Shift+F9 en même temps, la méthode editOrSubmit est appelée
        if(e.which == 120 && isCtrl && isShift) { 
            var icon = document.getElementById("icon");
            editOrSubmit(icon);
        } 
    });

});
```

It work well in a browser, but inside the test nothing happen ? Do you know why ?

Answer (score -1):

unfortunately Wicket and JUnit cannot test JavaScript code but just Java code. However, Wicket itself uses Maven and frontend-maven-plugin to run QUnit tests via Maven. You can take a look at Wicket code inside testing/wicket-js-tests (https://github.com/apache/wicket/tree/master/testing/wicket-js-tests) to see how this is done by Wicket and you can copy the code you need to run your tests.